# Calculating time between entries in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

Guys i have a table that has a column named time. It capture the time of each record entry in to the database. I want to query and return another column displaying the duration between one entry and the entry before it. Example, if i store record for john today at 12:00 pm, and then Ali at 1:10 pm, i want another column that will show 01:10:00 (i.e HH:MM:SS).

I understand i can query each column number as follows.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [followuptime]) from [dbo].[FollowUp] .
```

i wanted to query the max row number AS follows but it fails and return error "windowed...."

```
SELECT MAX(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [followuptime])) from [dbo].[FollowUp] .
```

I wanted to use the  `DATEDIFF(interval,start_time,end_time);`    function of sql , but as it is now, I am stuck. Please would appreciate your help or any alternative.

Comment: What version of SQL-Server are you using? 2012 supports that [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) and [LEAD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) functions that would make this very easy to get the previous time. --> `LAG(followuptime`) OVER(ORDER BY followuptime)`

Comment: Also if you do `MAX(ROW_NUMBER()...` with no PARTITION BY the maximum rownumber will be the same as `COUNT(*)`. So for your second query that fails : `SELECT MAX(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [followuptime])) from [dbo].[FollowUp]`, you could get the same result with --> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Followup`

Comment: SQL server 2012 and studio version 11.0.2100.60. But its saying LAG is not a built in function....

Comment: I run this for a test 'SELECT [id],[followuptime],[remark],LAG([followuptime],1,0) OVER 
(ORDER BY [followuptime]) FROM [dbo].[FollowUp]; ' but its saying LAG is not a valid expression. How ever it does recognize it before i execute though.

Comment: I don't see any reason this wouldn't work, are you definitely connecting to a 2012 instance? Your query works fine on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/afdcc/1)

Comment: I am really confused . It still returns "LAG is not a recognized expression". Also while typing LAG , it displays a relevant suggestion which is an evidence of the recognition of the said expression. I am not sure what the problem is now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35827/discussion-between-garethd-and-nuru-salihu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SQL-Server 2008R2 does not support LAG/LEAD you will need to do a self join using row_number to get the time from previous row:

```
WITH OrderedResults AS
(   SELECT  [id],
            [followuptime],
            [remark],
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [followuptime]) 
    FROM    [dbo].[FollowUp]
)
SELECT  a.ID, 
        a.FollowUpTime, 
        a.Remark, 
        PreviousTime = b.FollowUpTime,
        MinutesDifference = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, b.FollowUpTime, a.FollowUpTime)
FROM    OrderedResults a
        LEFT JOIN OrderedResults b
            ON b.RowNumber = a.RowNumber - 1
ORDER BY a.FollowUpTime;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f70c4/1)**

Answer (score 0):

You may not apply MAX to ROW_NUMBER. Use a CTE and query that.

```
;WITH MyCTE AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [followuptime]) AS RowNum
    FROM [dbo].[FollowUp]
)

SELECT MAX(RowNum)
FROM MyCTE
```